# Roc curve doesn't show on the graph (Sklearn-kNN)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn, roc

I have a k-NN algorithm that uses the parameters **K=3** and **cross-validation =10**, as shown below. This algorithm is made to run in a Dataset that can assume 2 values: background/normal and bot. When running the Dataset, that I'm making available below, it generates the following confusion matrix:

```
       confusion matrix
Background/Normal [[23553   136]
Bot               [  237  1786]]
```

and the following metrics:

```
                   precision    recall  f1-score   support

Background/Normal       0.99      0.99      0.99     23689
              Bot       0.93      0.88      0.91      2023

        micro avg       0.99      0.99      0.99     25712
        macro avg       0.96      0.94      0.95     25712
     weighted avg       0.99      0.99      0.99     25712


Cross Val Score
[0.97773673 0.98288936 0.98425044 0.96869531 0.96800856 0.98064955 0.97851031 0.97782964 0.95702061 0.95439518] 

Cross val avg: 0.9729985691978758 

RocAUC score: 0.9725001834719879
```

[CTU13/10 - Dataset Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xlw5cutigqqhzpr/CTU13%20-%20Dataset10.csv?dl=0)

The only problem is generating the ROC curve's graph. I don't understand why I'm getting this error since it generates an output for the metric command, roc_aus_score but on the graph it puts AUC=nan

```
print(metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_prob, average='micro'))
OUTPUT: RocAUC score: 0.9725001834719879
```

**graph output error**:
[Image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUjKe.png)

And show this Warning:

> Python3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\ranking.py:656: UndefinedMetricWarning: No positive samples in y_true, true positive value should be meaningless UndefinedMetricWarning)

*Program code*:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
from sklearn.metrics import auc

def openfile():
    df = pd.read_csv('TestfileBEB - kNN.csv')

    return df

def main():

    openfile= abrir()

    X = dataset.drop(columns=['Label'])
    y = dataset['Label'].values

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

    Classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3, p=2, metric='euclidean')
    Classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

    y_pred_class = Classifier.predict(X_test)

    score = cross_val_score(Classifier, X, y, cv=10)

    y_pred_prob = Classifier.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]


    print("accuracy_score:", metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred_class),'\n')
    print("confusion matrix")
    print(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_class),'\n')
    print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred_class, digits=2),'\n')
    print("Cross Val Score")
    print(score,'\n')
    print("Cross val avg:", score.mean(),'\n')
    print(metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_prob, average='micro'))


    fpr, tpr, threshold = roc_curve(y_test, y_pred_prob, pos_label=2)
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
    plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, 'b', label='AUC = %0.2f' % roc_auc)
    plt.legend(loc='lower right')
    plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'r--')
    plt.xlim([0, 1])
    plt.ylim([0, 1])
    plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
    plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
    plt.title('ROC Curve of kNN')
    plt.show()
```

I'd like to know what's wrong with the code and how I can improve it so the metric shows successfully.

Comment: Please, instead of irrelevant to the issue `title`, `legend` etc stuff, post the exact error trace - *where exactly* does the warning (*not* an error) pop up? At `roc_curve`, `auc`, `plot`...??

Comment: I tried, and it seems to work if you delete the argument 'pos_label=2' and convert your y_test to 0's and 1's. Hope this helps somewhat

Comment: You'd be more likely to get an answer if you reduced your example to a minimum example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: That means remove all the print, plot, etc. You can probably remove train_test_split and all the KNN stuff as well and still get the error. Finally, please, no external download! Reduce your dataset to the minimum as well, remove unused columns and most of the rows, to the point you can include it directly in your question. By that time the answer might become obvious enough that you'll be able to spot it yourself.

Comment: @Tacratis Thank you! Your comment helped me a lot.